# How do I pass parameters to a function from a guizero object?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, parameters, event-handling

I am unable to pass any parameter to a function called by a guizero widget either with the attribute "command"  at initialization or by invoking an event.

This works as expected (no parameters passed):

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

def go():
    print (10)

app = App(title="Test")
button = PushButton(app, text = "Click Here", command = go)

app.display()
```

but the following prints the number 10 **once, before** the button is clicked and then when I click,  nothing happens

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

def go(n):
    print (n)

app = App(title="Test")
button = PushButton(app, text = "Click Here", command = go(10))

app.display()
```

The same result I get with this:

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

def go(n):
    print (n)

app = App(title="Test")
button = PushButton(app, text = "Click Here")
button.when_clicked = go(10)

app.display()
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
from guizero import App, PushButton
def go(n):
    print (n)
app = App(title="Test")
button = PushButton(app, text = "Click Here", command = lambda: go(10))
app.display()
```

Whenever you write `go(10)` anywhere, you are invoking the function `go`. You might think you are passing `go` with arguments, but you aren't because the parentheses next to `go()` invoke the function right then and there. If you want to pass the function `go` to another function, and `go` should also be passed with some arguments, then you need to wrap the function `go` and pass the wrapped function as the argument "command". Using a lambda function to wrap `go(10)` is one such way of doing this.

The reason this works is that the lambda function is NOT invoked right then and there. You are saying that that `command()` should invoke the **declared** anonymous lambda function eventually, and when that lambda function is called it will itself call `go(10)`. You are **declaring** an anonymous lambda function, NOT invoking it. The lambda function will be invoked later on as `command()`.

Answer (score 1):

In all GUI frameworks `command=` (or similar) expects `callback` - it means function's name without `()` and without parameters.

---

If you use `go(10)` then it does

```
result = go(10)
PushButton( ...., command=result)
```

so it executes `go(10)` before you even click button - and it assign result to `command=`. Because `go()` returns `None` so you get `PushButton( ...., command=None)` and when you click button then you get nothing.

---

You have to create new function which you can run without `()`

```
def go_10():
    go(10)

PushButton( ...., command=go_10)
```

Or you can use `lambda` to create function directly in `command=`

```
PushButton( ...., command=lambda:go(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

Using a **lambda** function is a clever way to work around the callback limitation but I found a more proper way to pass arguments to a function by using the widget properties (pun not intended). As it turns out I missed a very brief reference to the property *args* that can be set at instantiation and is used to pass a list to the function called by *command*

So here is my solution:

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

def go(n):
    print (n)

app = App(title="Test")
button = PushButton(app, text = "Click Here", args = [10], command = go)

app.display()
```

As expected, it prints '10' every time you click the button and not before.

Thanks for all the other answers!